# inserting a directive every time a button is clicked

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am working from a tutorial here: https://fourtonfish.com/blog/2014-01-dynamically-add-directives-in-angularjs-no-jquery/

However, I want to create a directive and inject this into my HTML every time a button is clicked. After some reading around, my attempt is below. You will see that in main.js I have this code:

```
.directive('addfields',function($compile){
  console.log("directive called.");

  return function(scope,element){
    element.on("click",function(){
      var enviroElement = angular.element(document.createElement('enviroVariables'));
      var el = $compile(enviroElement)(scope);
      console.log(el);
      angular.element(document.getElementById('moreEnviromentVariables')).append($compile(el)(scope))
    })
  }
})
```

Here I am attempting to create an element, compile it, and then inject it. This doesn't work and I'm not sure why. I receive no errors. Any suggestions?

Full code:

main.html

```
  <div id ="fullForm" ng-controller="MainCtrl" >                
      <enviro-variables></enviro-variables>
<div id="moreEnviromentVariables"></div>
    </div>
                    <button-add></button-add>
```

main.js

```
 'use strict';

    /**
     * @ngdoc function
     * @name jsongeneratorApp.controller:MainCtrl
     * @description
     * # MainCtrl
     * Controller of the jsongeneratorApp
     */
    angular.module('jsongeneratorApp')
      .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {

      .directive('buttonAdd',function(){
        return{
        restrict:'E',
        templateUrl:'scripts/directives/addbutton.html'
      }
    })

   .directive('addfields',function($compile){
  console.log("directive called.");

  return function(scope,element){
    element.on("click",function(){
      var enviroElement = angular.element(document.createElement('enviroVariables'));
      var el = $compile(enviroElement)(scope);
      console.log(el);
      angular.element(document.getElementById('moreEnviromentVariables')).append($compile(el)(scope))
    })
  }
})
```

addbutton.html

```
<div class="row rowmargin">
  <div class="col-sm-9">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <button addfields class="btn"> Add New Variable</button>

  </div>
</div>
```

enviromentVariablesDiv.html

```
<div id = "formSection">
                  <div class="row rowmargin">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="key" id="key" ng-model="key" ng-change="updateJson()" ng-model-options="{debounce: 1000}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="value" ng-model="value" ng-change="updateJson()"  ng-model-options="{debounce: 1000}" >
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

see this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/eZTtRVTPb7k9kgS8woKh?p=preview and this [Inserting directives into HTML in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15503766/inserting-directives-into-html-in-angularjs)

to insert the directive into DOM you could use the following

Example:

> There are  different features that register in 
>   an angular service called `FeatureRegistry`. From there they are taken
>   and inserted into a sidebar from an `FeatureSelectionController`. By
>   clicking on a feature the `startFeature()` function of the appropriate
>   feature should be invoked

in the html this can be solved like this:

```
<feature ng-repeat="f in registry.all()" model="f" state="list">
<feature ng-repeat="f in registry.maximized()" model="f" state="open">
<feature ng-repeat="f in registry.minimized()" model="f" state="minimized">
```

> Then in your directive template, you could have your common
>   functionality then determine what to have depending on the state using
>   `ng-switch` or `ng-show`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I should have been clearer sorry, I want a new element to be generated every time the button is clicked, not just open and close the same one.